# How to sort these out in R

Tags: r

I have the following data :

```r
       df<-read.table (text=" ID    KO1a    P1  P2  P3  Ko1b    P4  P5  P6  Time1   KO2a    P7  P8  P9  Ko2b    P10 P11 P12 Time2
    
        1   1   2   1   2   3   2   2   4   1   5   2   1   2   7   2   2   4   2
        2   1   2   2   2   3   1   3   2   1   5   2   2   2   7   1   3   2   2
        3   2   4   3   1   4   3   3   3   1   6   4   3   1   8   3   3   3   2
        4   2   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   1   6   4   4   4   8   4   4   4   2
    
        ", header=TRUE)
```

I want to get this table:

```
ID  Ko  Time    P   value
1   1   1   P1  2
1   1   1   P2  1
1   1   1   P3  2
1   3   1   P4  2
1   3   1   P5  2
1   3   1   P6  4
1   5   2   P7  2
1   5   2   P8  1
1   5   2   P9  2
1   7   2   P10 2
1   7   2   P11 2
1   7   2   P12 4
2   1   1   P1  2
2   1   1   P2  2
2   1   1   P3  2
2   3   1   P4  1
2   3   1   P5  3
2   3   1   P6  2
2   5   2   P7  2
2   5   2   P8  2
2   5   2   P9  2
2   7   2   P10 1
2   7   2   P11 3
2   7   2   P12 2
3   2   1   P1  4
3   2   1   P2  3
3   2   1   P3  1
3   4   1   P4  3
3   4   1   P5  3
3   4   1   P6  3
3   6   2   P7  4
3   6   2   P8  3
3   6   2   P9  1
3   8   2   P10 3
3   8   2   P11 3
3   8   2   P12 3
4   2   1   P1  4
4   2   1   P2  4
4   2   1   P3  4
4   4   1   P4  4
4   4   1   P5  4
4   4   1   P6  4
4   6   2   P7  4
4   6   2   P8  4
4   6   2   P9  4
4   8   2   P10 4
4   8   2   P11 4
4   8   2   P12 4
```

I tried to use `pivot_longer()` in `tidyr`, but I failed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *"but I failed"*, it is usually better to see your attempt so that we can correct the logic you used to construct the expression.

Comment: df %>%  pivot_longer(cols = ID, names_to = c("value", "ko","Time"))

Comment: aren't you missing the ```values_to``` argument? For example, when pivoting ```time```: newdf <- df %>% 
       pivot_longer(c(Time1, Time2),
                 names_to = c("TIME"),
                 values_to = "VALUE") %>% 
    select(TIME, VALUE)